# Smooth Scrolling to a Button - How to Fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have created a button on my website, and wish for it to have smooth scrolling on click. I have created something which i thought would work however does not. Any ideas or fixes. Many Thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="col col-sm-12 span-12">
  <div class="about-btn">
    <button id="about-smooth-scrolling-btn"><strong>CONTACT US</strong></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.about-btn button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000E47;
    color: #000E47;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 1s;
}

.about-btn button:hover {
    background-color: #000E47;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

JS

```
$("#about-smooth-scrolling-btn").click(function () {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#about-section").offset().top
  }, 2000);
})
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are doing a `$("#about-section")` but this id doesn't exist.

Comment: this is probably because the provided html is incomplete @Ben

Comment: @Ramon de Vries Probably yes, but just want to be sure, I've seen those kind of typos when trying multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. This code is using jQuery but you do not have it included. Also you did not added "jquery" tag to this question so I'm guessing that you did not have it and think that this is plain JS example.
2. There is no "#about-section" in code.

After including jquery and adding missing div everything works.

```js
$("#about-smooth-scrolling-btn").click(function () {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#about-section").offset().top
  }, 2000);
})
```

```css
.about-btn button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000E47;
    color: #000E47;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 1s;
}

.about-btn button:hover {
    background-color: #000E47;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col col-sm-12 span-12">
  <div class="about-btn">
    <button id="about-smooth-scrolling-btn"><strong>CONTACT US</strong></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
<div id="about-section">ABOUT SECTION Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam omnis ratione incidunt accusamus praesentium eaque quod ipsum expedita libero, veniam et maiores autem reiciendis accusantium. Voluptatum quidem nostrum inventore at?</div>
```

Comment: Yep sorry, forgot to add. I have an ID for about-section present in my html, but forgot to add that in. Knowing what would i need to do to fix the issue with the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        .about-btn button {
            background-color: transparent;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-color: #000E47;
            color: #000E47;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: auto;
            transition: 1s;
        }

        .about-btn button:hover {
            background-color: #000E47;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #fff;
            margin: auto;
            transition: 1s;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="col col-sm-12 span-12">
        <div class="about-btn">
            <button id="about-smooth-scrolling-btn"><strong>CONTACT US</strong></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="about-section">About</div>
    <script crossorigin='anonymous' integrity='sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js'></script>
    <script>
    $("#about-smooth-scrolling-btn").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#about-section").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```